# How can I calculate the distance between an object and a single camera with opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to take video from a regular webcam and use opencv (or maybe some other framework) to calculate the depth of an object? (the distance from the camera)

Would it be possible to do this without knowing beforehand how large the object was going to be?

How can I do this, where should I start?

Comment: It is impossible to measure the depth with a single camera, the minimum is 2 cameras, you could read about disparity algorithm.

Comment: To calculate the size of the object you can compare images that were taken a known distance delta from the object. For instance move two feet closer. First order of accuracy depends on how accurate the distance change was.

Comment: If you take a video from one single camera of the object, but two perpendicular views, then it is possible